# Get Staking Positions via Binance API

Tags: api, binance

Is there a way to track your staking positions? All the Savings positions seem to be easy to reference through the API but it doesn't appear that it supports any of the staking functionality (lists, positions, history, purchasing, etc).

I've poured through the Savings section of the [API documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#savings-endpoints) but it doesn't seem to support staking, nor is it in the wallet endpoints.

Comment: I've the same question as you. It seems it is not yet available by API

Comment: seems so basic. can't find it too still

Comment: They had added staking api recently, doc: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#change-log

Answer (score 1):

You can get your current staking positions by doing a signed GET request to this endpoint

```
/sapi/v1/staking/position
```

And get your staking history through this endpoint

```
/sapi/v1/staking/stakingRecord
```

For more information about these endpoints and what parameters should be included in the requests, see the official [Binance API documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#get-staking-product-position-user_data)

Comment: Do you know if its possible to reference a reward to a staking position? For example maybe via the positionId?